# Sync iCal and contact with Windows Mobile 6.5 in OSX Lion

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, ical, contacts

How can I sync iCal and Address Book with Windows Mobile 6.5 in OS X Lion?

I would prefer a simple solution. I very much don't want this information on the Internet and am willing to wait for my Windows Mobile to be in the same location as my mac for syncs to happen.

I have tried The Missing Sync but it does not support Lion.

Comment: I know a lot of people looking for inexpensive macs to run Lion Server for this purpose. A fairly secure CalDAV server of your own for $49.99 plus hardware is a powerful tool to have these days.

Comment: I am really looking for a simple offline solution that doesn't require to put sensible data "into to internet". I just want to plug my one and only phone to my one and only mac and events and contact should synchronize. Also CalDAV is a pain with Windows Mobile.